# Automatic detection of column unit and unit conversion

Tags: python

I need to automatically detect the units of the columns and convert to correct the unit and rename the column.

The standard units should be:

```
 'Inch'(In) for 'Height' column 
 'Degree Celcius'(°C) for 'Temperature' column.
```

Sample tables shown below where units need to be converted. The table could have mixture of units, some need to be converted and some that don't. Any idea?

```
Height (mm)  Temperature(°F)
16                    27
12                    30
17                    32
20                    23
14                    43

Height (mm)  Temperature(°C)
14                   31
13                   42
19                    50
22                    28
18                    36

1 mm = 0.0393701 inch
T(°C) = (T(°F) - 32) × 5/9
```

Comment: Where is the units, in the columns names or in the values  (25°C) ? Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa the unit is in the column header name as shown in the table above. The column values are numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the columns names with `.filter` method, then apply your conversion and finally rename:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Height (mm)':[16,12,17,20,14],'Temperature(°F)':[27,30,32,23,43]})
print('before conversion',df)
for x in df.filter(like='°F',axis=1).keys():
    df[x] = (df[x] - 32) * 5/9
    df.rename(columns={x:x.replace('°F','°C')}, inplace=True)

for x in df.filter(like='(mm)',axis=1).keys():
    df[x] = df[x] * 0.0393701
    df.rename(columns={x:x.replace('(mm)','(In)')}, inplace=True)
print('After conversion',df)
```

output looks like:

```
before conversion    
Height (mm)  Temperature(°F)
0           16               27
1           12               30
2           17               32
3           20               23
4           14               43
After conversion
Height (In)  Temperature(°C)
0     0.629922        -2.777778
1     0.472441        -1.111111
2     0.669292         0.000000
3     0.787402        -5.000000
4     0.551181         6.111111
```

Comment: thanks very much! that is how i want the output to be @Juan Javier Santos Ochoa